# Phonegap(ios): can not return to site after paypal payment

Tags: ios, cordova, paypal, return

I am developing an app using phonegap 2.9 for both android and iOS. I have implemented paypal payment process using in-app browser, everything works fine on android but in iOS a small problem after the payment is done when it is supposed to redirected on success page it shows 'Load Error' and can not return to the success page.

I have not set any auto return url for the merchant account. I also tried to set it but still the same problem on iOS

**the same script runs fine** on Android app

The data sent on server is:

```
$config = array(
             'cmd' => '_xclick', 
             'business' => $seller['paypal_email'], 
             'return' => $success_url , 
             'undefined_quantity' => 0, 
             'item_name' => $item_list, 
             'item_number' => '#some number#', 
             'notify_url' => $notify_url, 
             'currency_code' => 'USD', 
             'amount' => $order_total,
             'no_shipping' => 1,
             'custom' => $order_id, 
             'cancel_return' => $failure_url
           );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Actually it was caused because of my project setup was done for Xcode 4, and recently i have updated XCode to 5, so there was some kind of conflict. When i re configured my project for Xcode 5, the problem automatically solved.

Answer (score 3):

There is a PayPal Cordova Plugin for 2.0 PayPal Mobile SDK. Not sure if it will meet your needs but you welcome to check it out. It requires Phonegap 3.0 though ...

https://github.com/paypal/paypal-cordova-plugin